# Why would my Iranian website only appear in search results outside Iran?

Tags: google-search, search, country-specific, international

I have a shopping site in Iran, but when I search in Google, it won't come up in the search results.  The only way I can find the site at all in Google from inside Iran is after a long search in image results.

When i connect to VPN I can find my pages in the search results.  For example, when I connect to Germany, Netherlands or France (changing my IP address), I can find my pages in results.

How can I get Google to show my site in Iranian based results.

Comment: What language(s) is your website written in? Can you find your site using a `site:` search?

Answer (score 1):

First of All, Is your website hosted in Iran and do you have a **.ir** TLD?

Additionally, you can improve your local search ranking by using Google My Business services.

Here are a few tips to improve your local search ranking.

https://moz.com/blog/unfiltered-local-search-results

Comment: host is located in germany. a couple of iranian sites use germany hostings. yes my site is gymarket.ir

Comment: It would be a good thing to ask your host to give you an iranian ip. I can't read persian so I can't see if you mention in text your website is dedicated to Iran market? It's very important to mention that also. eg **The 1st iranian gym provider**

Comment: Server IP address should not be a (significant) factor when geo-targeting a website. Except that if a site is physically hosted far from your expected user base then there might delays when serving content.